# Chrome Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 when trying to XHR a file in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to request the chrome extensions manifest file (my own extension)

```
// MAKE MANIFEST FILE AVAILABLE
chrome.manifest = (function() {
    var manifestObject = false;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            manifestObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('/manifest.json'), false);
    try {
        xhr.send();
    } catch(e) {
        log('Couldn\'t load manifest.json');
    }
    return manifestObject;
})();
```

but I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 (anonymous
>   function)cm_background.js:46 (anonymous function)

line 46 being `xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('/manifest.json'), false);`

What would the appropriate manifest security policy be to allow me to do this, or an alternative safe way?

### Update

#### Manifest file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "A plugin",
  "version":"1.3.6",
  "background": {
    "page":"cm_background.html"
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_title": "A plugin",
    "default_popup": "cm_popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://mail.google.com/*", "https://mail.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js",
             "underscore.js",
             "sha256.js",
             "utils.js",
             "cm_content_script.js",
             "cm_content_ui_control.js",
             "cm_first_install.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions" : [
    "tabs",
    "http://mail.google.com/*",
    "https://mail.google.com/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "chrome-extension://*/*"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "manifest.json",
    "cm_first_install.js",
    "jquery.js",
    "cm_signature_editor.css",
    "cm_signature_editor.html"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src *;"
}
```

Comment: How does your manifest look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this method give you the information you need?

```
chrome.app.getDetails()
```

It doesn't appear to be documented in the API, but it returns most of the data from the manifest.